# Editable InputField In React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
export default function UserProfile(props) {
  const { isLoggedIn, user, profile  } = useSelector((state) => state.AuthReducer);
  const { wallet, paired_curency_price, coins, wallet_loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.coinDBReducer
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
  const [nodisplay, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [total_btc, setTotalBtc] = useState(0);
  const [total_usdt, setTotalUsdt] = useState(0);
  const updateProfile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checkName(name)) {
      N_updateName(
        user?.params ? user.params.token: user.token,
        name
      ).then((res) => {
        if (res.status.matchedCount == 1) {
          setName("");
          setDisplay(!nodisplay);
          N_getProfile(user?.params ? user.params.token: user.token)
        .then((d) => {
          if (d.status === 200) {
            dispatch({type:'PROFILE', data:d?.params.profile_info})
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
          NotificationManager.success("Updated Successfully");
        } else {
          NotificationManager.error(res.message);
        }
      });
    } else {
      NotificationManager.error("Enter valid nick Name");
    }
  };

  <main className="s-layout__content">
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="account_page">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <div className="jambotron">
            <div className="horizontal_display_with_justify">
              <div className="flex_row">
                {" "}
                <div className="name_circle">
                  {profile?.name
                    ? profile?.name
                      ?.split("")
                      .slice(0, 2)
                      .join("")
                      .toUpperCase()
                    : profile?.email
                       ?.split("")
                       .slice(0, 2)
                       .join("")
                       .toUpperCase()}
                </div>
                {" "}
                {nodisplay 
                  ? <><span>Hello</span>
                    <div>
                      <input
                        className="editable-input-box"
                        type="text"
                        contentEditable={true}
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setName(e.target.value.replace("/a-zA-z*/i", ""));
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                    </>
                  : <div className="big_heading text-capitalize me-2 text-truncate mob_mw_150">
                      {" "}Hello,{" "}
                      {hide
                        ? "**********"
                        : profile?.name
                        ? profile.name
                        : profile?.email}{" "}
                    </div>}
                    <div>
                      {nodisplay ?
                        <>
                          <div className="d-flex gap-1">
                            <button
                              className="btn btn-pink btn-sm fs-14"
                              onClick={(e) => {
                                updateProfile(e);
                              }}
                            >
                              Update
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </> : <></>  
                      }
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <span
                        className="cursor_pointer"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setDisplay(!nodisplay);
                          setName(profile?.name)
                        }}
                      >
```

In this code inputfield  show the inputfield in when edit cursor show inputfiled but my question is when i click edit cursor not show inputfield only edit at same place and click update button update at same place and  edit at same place not open new input field i click edit cursor edit text not show inputfield in the brwser

Comment: Where Changes In This Code

Answer (score 0):

Ok use conditional rendering to achieve this, here's an example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function UserProfile(props) {
  // ... Other code ...

  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const toggleEditing = () => {
    setIsEditing(!isEditing);
    setName(profile?.name);
  };

  return (
    <main className="s-layout__content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="account_page">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <div className="jambotron">
              <div className="horizontal_display_with_justify">
                <div className="flex_row">
                  <div className="name_circle">
                    {profile?.name
                      ? profile?.name
                        ?.split("")
                        .slice(0, 2)
                        .join("")
                        .toUpperCase()
                      : profile?.email
                          ?.split("")
                          .slice(0, 2)
                          .join("")
                          .toUpperCase()}
                  </div>
                  {isEditing ? (
                    <div>
                      <input
                        className="editable-input-box"
                        type="text"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setName(e.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="big_heading text-capitalize me-2 text-truncate mob_mw_150">
                      {" "}Hello,{" "}
                      {hide
                        ? "**********"
                        : profile?.name
                        ? profile.name
                        : profile?.email}{" "}
                    </div>
                  )}
```

I introduced a state variable "isEditing: to control if the input field is shown.

It's based on toggling

Depending on the value of isEditing, you can conditionally render either the input field or the name. When editing is enabled, the input field is shown; otherwise, the name is displayed.

Comment: Yes But This code not allow to edit name and not show update button

Comment: Update Button Are Show Not edit name in the place and not show inputbox